# Generating set of the real numbers under addition

Tags: group-theory

How would one generate $(R,+)$? If you took an arbitrarily small interval, would this work? How can you prove that this is so?

Comment: Do you allow subtraction?

Comment: Yes. Any interval with non-empty interior will generate $(\Bbb{R},+)$ as a group.

Comment: Yes @quid, I do!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $A = (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$ is a nonempty interval at zero. We will show this interval generates all of $\mathbb R$. For any $x \in \mathbb R$ the sequence $x/n$ tends to zero (Observe that this fact is equivalent to the Archimidean property). So some $x/n$ is equal to an element, say $a \in A$. Then we have $na = a + a + \ldots a = x$ is generated by interval elements, as required.

Now suppose $B = (b-\varepsilon, b+\varepsilon)$ is any nonempty interval. Let $G$ be the group generated by $B$. Since $b \in B$ we know $b'-b \in G$ for each $b' \in B$. So $G$ contains the interval $B-b = (-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$. Then $G$ contains every element generated by $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$, which we have already shown is all of $\mathbb R$.

$\square$

Comment: $x/n\to0$ is equivalent to the Archimedean Property. You ought make that explicit.

Comment: Okay dokey, Nobody.

Comment: what about if I take the interval (0,x) (x>0) and I allow subtraction? Am I right in thinking that would work too?

Comment: Then let $\varepsilon = b = x/2$ and look at what the second half of the proof says.